# Change CSS transition start and ending position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
var ImageTrigger = false;

$(document).on('click', 'body img', function() {
  if (!ImageTrigger) {
    $(this).addClass("imgclick");
    ImageTrigger = true;
    return false;
  }
});
$(document).on('click', 'body', function() {
  if (ImageTrigger) {
    $("img").removeClass("imgclick");
    ImageTrigger = false;
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 90%;
}
.imgclick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* transform-origin: 0px center 0px; */
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15px 15px 50px;
  z-index: 100001;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="imgclick" style="max-height: 400px;max-width:50%;margin: 0 auto;display: table;" src="http://www.biologicaldiversity.org/assets/img/species/mammals/GrayWolf_USFWS_FPWC_2_HIGHRES-scr.jpg" alt="image alt" title="Cool">
```

I am trying to make entrance look like the same image zoomed out from original position and came in center and on exit it goes back to its place the same way it came. I tried using `transform-origin` but no luck.

Also any clean way to make image occupy 90% screen with out distorting aspect ratio?

EDIT:

Upon clicking on image, the image comes in from bottom right and upon returning it comes from top left. I am trying to make it look like it came in from original image and goes back to to original image instead of top left and bottom right.

Initial code i was using

```
.imgclick{
    max-height: 400px; 
    max-width: 95%; 
    margin: 0px auto; 
    display: table; 
    transform: scale(1.44); 
    transform-origin: left center 0px; 
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.611765) 0px 0px 13px; 
    z-index: 100001; 
    padding: 10px; 
    background: white; 
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.img{
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    max-width:90%;
    transform: scale(1);
}


.imgclick{
            transform: scale(1.2);
            box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15px 15px 50px;
            z-index: 100001;
            padding: 10px;
            background: white;
}
```

I am little confused what exactly you are trying. But above code does zoom in and zoom out. You can modify to your need. :)

Comment: See my updated question. And i dont wish to use `scale` i was using scale and changed to `transition`.

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
}


.imgclick{
            transform: scale(1.4,1.4);
            box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15px 15px 50px;
            z-index: 100001;
            padding: 10px;
            background: white;
}
```

I hope above code helps you. (second answer)

Comment: Thanks @Rupesh for code snippet. Unfortunately the parent div containing these image tag does not cover full width of my screen and i wish to display the enlarged image in the center of my screen like an album view with height being a controlling factor (80%) not scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the img centered inside a div can make the effect you need

```js
$(document).on('click', 'body img', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("imgSmall") || $(this).hasClass("imgClick"))
    $(this).toggleClass("imgSmall imgClick");
  else
    $(this).addClass("imgClick")
  return false;
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 1s linear all;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes imageBig {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px #888888;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
@keyframes imgSmall {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px #888888;
    width: 90%;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
.imgClick {
  animation-name: imageBig;
}
.imgSmall {
  animation-name: imgSmall;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://www.biologicaldiversity.org/assets/img/species/mammals/GrayWolf_USFWS_FPWC_2_HIGHRES-scr.jpg" alt="image alt" title="Cool">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the fixed position under a div, but unfortunately i require this image to popup at center of the screen and `NO` parent div cant go 100% width as there is another html element at right hand side. Assume this image a part of a post and when clicked it covers up the whole screen as in showcase view.